# proposed tag synonyms: rails3.1 and ruby-on-rails3.1

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I don't have the credit to suggest this, but it's a no-brainer: Make [rails3.1](/questions/tagged/rails3.1) a synonym of [ruby-on-rails-3.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-3.1).

Comment: Is there a reason that you need [tag:ruby-on-rails], [tag:ruby-on-rails-3], and [tag:ruby-on-rails-3.1]?  [144 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails+ruby-on-rails-3+ruby-on-rails-3.1) are tagged with all three.

Comment: There are questions that are specific to specific versions, which is why all three tags are useful. There are people who can answer a ruby-on-rails-3.1 question but who are only subscribed to the ruby-on-rails tag, which is why it is advantageous to tag a question with both. I agree that it's messy, but this is what creates that behavior.